# Is it possible to insert DNA without cutting the recognition site with CRISPR/Cas9?

Tags: dna, synthetic-biology

We are looking for a way to insert DNA into a genome, but we would like to do it in a way that the recognition site stay intact to be able to add again DNA at the same location. Do you know if it is possible or if it is already the way CRISPR/Cas9 does it? Apparently multiple systems were already engineered but the few papers we read weren't about our problem.

Sincerely,

Emilie

Comment: Inserting into the genome of what organism?

Comment: Why not just make sure your inserted DNA segment contains the same CRISPR/Cas recognition site, so you can just cut it again?

Comment: @MarchHo I had the same thought initially, but then Cas would cut your target DNA as well. Furthermore, the target DNA would also have a region of homology which doesn't contain your desired insert and repair could occur which doesn't result in insertion of your desired sequence.

Comment: We would like to use it on E.coli genome.

Comment: @canadianer And Cas9 ignores methylation too. Perhaps try another nuclease (eg ZFN or TALEN) which is affected by methylation?

Comment: @EmilieCuillery Is there any reason you cannot just use a plasmid?

Comment: The nice thing about CRISPR/Cas is that target recognition is done by RNA, which is relatively easy/cheap to obtain. Could you just get another gRNA which recognizes the new sequence after insertion?

Comment: @MarchHo we could do that but then we would have little sequences coming from the former recognition sites "polluting" our added DNA. Our question would be more then: Do you know if Cas9 cuts in the middle of the recognition site or if a special engineered protein Cas that cuts after the recognition site (Whatever the sequence to cut is) exists?

Comment: What we want to do is to insert again and again the same sequence at the same location using only one recognition site. Does it seem crazy? we've been searching, looking for few days now but still have problems understanding real mechanism of CRISPR/CAS9... @MarchHo we'll use a plasmid for sure to get the protein we want be then we want our protein to act over and over by adding DNA again and again each time increasing the genome (with notion of order)

Comment: I'm not sure about an engineered Cas, but I think nucleases like TALEN don't cleave the recognition sequence. The problem I think you'll face is that your insert must also contain the recognition sequence to be homologous and would thus also get cleaved. You might consider using a mutated recognition sequence in the insert so that it isn't cleaved but still has sufficient homology to be used for repair. Even then, I would expect the target sequence in the gDNA to be replaced by the mutated version in the insert as nucleotides are resected from the double strand break.

Comment: @canadianer "Cas would cut your target DNA as well" - what about protecting the target DNA somehow?

Comment: I think the best option would be to add [protecting groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protecting_group) which can be removed later after Cas9 is cleared. If it is cleared ever. I have low skills by genetic engineering. :D

Answer (score 1):

Look into [site-specific recombination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site-specific_recombination).  You can use a site-specific recombinase, specifically an integrase, that can insert a sequence of DNA at a certain attachment site.  You can add an identical attachment site into the DNA sequence to insert, allowing for the reintegration of a new attachment site.  Note however that you might get SSR onto the insertion plasmid itself, so don't do this if you need a specific amount of integration.

[image: Look at the bottom subfigure of A for an example of integration.]

Look at the bottom subfigure of A for an example of integration.  Recombinases can also do other things, such as excision and inversion, based on the orientation of the attachment sites.

Comment: Doesn't use CRISPR though. Right?

Comment: It seems that this also suffers from the same issues as pointed out in the comments. If your insert has the recombination site, it may recombine with copies of itself.

Comment: Our projects is basically based onto recombinase. And work...published 2 months ago ... but not by us :( So we are looking for a better efficiency (10^-4 with recombinase) allowing a faster system. As i understand CRISPR/Cas9 doesn't allow insertion of several piece of DNA at the same place butCas9 is a very powerful tool do you think we could engineer it to cut not the homologous sequence but just after of before? (We really have problems understanding where the DNA we want to insert is coming from and the exact mechanism of it. Are you thinking of another way faster than recombinase?

Comment: Anyway thank you all for your help but i think we will abandon the idea for now as we learned in our researches that the Cas9 rate and efficiency is much too low to do what we want... i'm sorry ! But thank you again for your help :)